# Asymptotics for series $\sum_{n \leq x} n/\log n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, analytic-number-theory

What can be said about an equivalent of
$$\sum_{n \leqslant x} \frac{n}{\log n}$$

I would like to compare it to $x^2$ which is approximately $\sum_{n \leqslant x} n$. Is it negligible in front of it? I tried partial summation and dyadic cutting, but nothing seems to work...

More generally, given a function $f$, is it true that $\sum \frac{f(n)}{\log(n)^\varepsilon}$ is negligible compared to $\sum f(n)$?

Comment: It looks like $$\sum_{n\leqslant x}\frac{n}{\log n} \approx \frac{x^2}{2 \log x}.$$

Comment: @Oleg567 How do we reach that? It seems like pulling out the $\log$, and indeed it is what I hope for, but without having any justification. Have you done partial summation?

Comment: Just observation via WolframAlpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(int_%7Bn%3D2%7D%5E%7B10%5E40%7D+n%2Fln(n))+%2F+((10%5E40)%5E2+%2F+ln(10%5E40)) , placing there $10^{10}, 10^{20}, 10^{40}, 10^{80}$ etc.

Comment: @Oleg567 Oh, a first enthusiasming evidence!

Answer (score 2):

By the [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 2}^x {\frac{n}{{\log n}}}  = \int_2^x {\frac{t}{{\log t}}{\rm d}t}  + \frac{x}{{2\log x}} + \mathcal{O}(1).
$$
Now taking $t=\sqrt{s}$,
$$
\int_2^x {\frac{t}{{\log t}}{\rm d}t}  = \int_4^{x^2 } {\frac{{{\rm d}s}}{{\log s}}}  = \int_2^{x^2 } {\frac{{{\rm d}s}}{{\log s}}}  + \mathcal{O}(1) = \operatorname{Li}(x^2 ) + \mathcal{O}(1),
$$
where $\operatorname{Li}(x)$ is the [logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Offset_logarithmic_integral). Using the known [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Asymptotic_expansion) of the logarithmic integral, we finally have
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 2}^x {\frac{n}{{\log n}}}  \sim \frac{{x^2 }}{{2\log x}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{k!}}{{2^k \log ^k x}}} 
$$
as $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: Nice + beautiful + (+1). Cheers

Comment: @Gary. How do you know the term after $\frac{x}{2\ln(x)}$ is $\mathcal{O}(1)$ after the Euler-Maclaurin? Sorry for the naive question.

Comment: @bob If you compute more terms in the Euler–Maclaurin formula, you will see it.

Comment: @Gary. $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2k-1)}(x)-f^{(2k-1)}(2)\right)$. I understand how the term $f^{(2k-1)}(2)=\mathcal{O}(1)$, but how does the term $f^{(2k-1)}(x)=\mathcal{O}(1)$?

Comment: @bob Have you tried computing the first few derivatives of $x/\log x$?

Comment: @Gary. $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\ln(x)-1}{\ln^2(x)}=\frac{1}{\ln(x)}-\frac{1}{\ln^2(x)}=\mathcal{O}(1)\ \text{as}\ x\to\infty$. Which is also true for all further derivatives. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @bob More or less. You should introduce an error term. For example show that $$
\frac{1}{{12}}(f'(x) - f'(2)) + \frac{1}{6}\int_2^x {f'''(t)B_3 (t - \left\lfloor t \right\rfloor ){\rm d}t} 
$$ is bounded for $x\ge 2$ ($f(x)=x/\log x$).

Comment: @Gary. Makes sense. So that's where the $R_p$ terms comes from. For convenience sake, is there a way to know the $\mathcal{O}(\cdot)$ without calculating by hand? I appreciate the help.

Comment: @bob To estimate the error of this and other types of quadrature formulae you need some knowledge on the derivative(s).

Answer (score 1):

Let $$s_n = \sum^n_{k=2} \frac{k}{\log k}.$$ Then, obviously $s_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_{n+1}-s_n}{(n+1)^2-n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{(2n+1)\log(n+1)}=0.$$ Due to the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), this implies
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_n}{n^2}=0.$$
For your more general question, you can just replace $n^2$ by $\sum_{k\le n}f(k)$ and $\log(n)$ by $\log(n)^\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

For an increasing function $f(x)$, we have that
$$ \sum_{a \leq n \leq b} f(n) \leq \int_a^{b+1} f(t) dt.$$
So we are led to consider
$$ \begin{align}
\int_2^X \frac{t}{\log t}\,dt &= \frac{t^2}{\log t} \Big|_2^X - \int_2^X t \left( \frac{t}{\log t}\right)' dt  \\
&=\frac{t^2}{\log t} \Big|_2^X - \int_2^X \frac{t(\log t - 1)}{\log^2 t} dt \\ =\frac{t^2}{\log t} \Big|_2^X - \int_2^X \frac{t}{\log t} dt + 
\int_2^X \frac{t}{\log^2 t} dt.
\end{align}$$
Rearranging, we have that
$$ \begin{align}
2 \int_2^X \frac{t}{\log t} dt &= \frac{t^2}{\log t} \Big|_2^X + \int_2^X \frac{t}{\log^2 t} dt \\
&= \frac{X^2}{\log X} - 4/\log 4 + \int_2^X \frac{t}{\log^2 t} dt\leq \frac{X^2}{\log X} + \frac{X^2}{\log^2 X}+ c
\end{align}$$
for a small constant $c$. Thus
$$ \int_2^X \frac{t}{\log t} dt = \frac{X^2}{2 \log X} + \frac{X^2}{2 \log^2 X}+ c.$$

A similar argument gives a similar lower bound, so that the leading order estimate of your sum is
$$ \frac{X^2}{2 \log X},$$
as expected from the comments. Performing further integration by parts actually leads to further terms in the expansion, where each term is a logarithmic savings over the previous. This is analogous to one way of proving the asymptotics for the logarithmic integral $\int dt/\log(t)$.

It is clear that this sort of argument will hold whenever $f$ is a well-enough behaved (e.g. monotonic, integrable). For a slightly worse-behaving class of functions $f$, one can replace the naive sum-and-integral bound with the first few terms of an Euler-Maclaurin sum, as long as $f$ is a few-times differentiable.

Comment: I think the easiest way is $\frac{n}{\log n} = \frac{(n+1)^2}{2 \log(n+1)} -\frac{n^2}{2 \log n} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{n}{\log^2 n})$ where the error term can be manipulated to give $ \frac{(n+1)^2}{4 \log^2 (n+1)} -\frac{n^2}{4 \log^2 n} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{n}{\log^3 n}) =  \ldots $. By induction we can show then  $\sum_{2 \le n \le x} \frac{n}{\log n} = \sum_{m=1}^M c_m  \frac{n^2}{\log^m n} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{n^2}{\log^{M+1} n}) $

Answer (score 1):

By [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts),

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{n}{\log n}&=&\frac{N^2+N-2}{2\log N}+\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\frac{(n^2+n-2)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{2\log(n)\log(n+1)}\\&=&\frac{N^2}{2\log N}+O(N)+\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{n}{2\log^2 n}\\&=&\frac{N^2}{2\log N}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{\log N}\right)\right). \end{eqnarray*} $$

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram Alpha says

$$\int \frac x{\ln x}dx=\operatorname{Ei}(2\log x).$$

Then it is known that

$$\frac12e^{-x}\log\left(1+\frac2x\right)\le-\operatorname{Ei}(-x)\le e^{-x}\log\left(1+\frac1x\right).$$

This shows that your sum is asymptotic to

$$\frac{cx^2}{\log x}.$$